# what is the default orientation of the iPad?

Tags: ios, css, ipad, ios6, orientation

I have heard a few conflicting comments regarding the default orientation of the iPad.

Some say it is portrait (how I tend to use my iPad), however some say it is landscape.

I have this sort of thing in my CSS to target elements when the device is in portrait mode, however I find I don't have the same sort of scaling problems with landscape and hence have no need for the media query below.

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) {

}
```

I can't find anything anywhere that says for sure what the default orientation is for the device. Is there one?

Comment: It differs from the iPhone. For the iPad, it's whichever way you're holding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default. Both are allowed and equally important. The fact that you only have problems with portrait is most probably just a consequence of this specific site's design, for others you'll have to do the same on landscape.

Since landscape presents a 1024px wide browser to the user it's also less probable to cause issues since desktop sites are historically nearly always 960 to 1050 pixels wide as well. That doesn't make it the 'default' though, just less likely to cause problems.

It's actually identical to asking what the default screen size is for a desktop browser - it doesn't have one, you can resize it at will. Rotating your iPad is for all intents and purposes just that, a sudden resize of the browser.

Comment: I'm not sure why you were down-voted, here's a +1. Your answer makes sense and I suppose if there is nothing in the Apple documentation it probably means that there isn't one. It would be good if Apple documented the fact there _wasn't_ one though - which would save people from making wrong assumptions.